# Функция проверки содержания определенных слов в строке

Tags: javascript, функции

*Задача*: Необходимо написать функцию `checkForSpam(str)`

Функция принимает 1 параметр str - строку,
  и проверять ее на содержание слов: spam и sale

Если нашли зарещенное слово то функция возвращает true,
  если запрещенных слов нет функция возвращает false

PS: слова могут быть в произвольном регистре

Как подправить код ниже, чтобы получить результат из комментариев к `console.log` после вызова функции

```
'use strict';
const checkForSpam = function (str) {
  let arrStr = str.split(' ');

  for (let i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i += 1) {
    let word = arrStr[i].toLowerCase;

    if (arrStr[i].toLowerCase === 'spam' || arrStr[i].toLowerCase === 'sale') {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

};

// Вызовы функции для проверки

console.log( checkForSpam('Latest technology news') ); // false

console.log( checkForSpam('JavaScript weekly newsletter') ); // false

console.log( checkForSpam('Get best sale offers now!') ); // true

console.log( checkForSpam('[SPAM] How to earn fast money?') ); // true
```

Comment: А в чем проблема с существующим кодом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например, так ?

```js
'use strict';
const checkForSpam = function (str) {
  return /\b(spam|sale)\b/i.test(str);
};

// Вызовы функции для проверки
console.log( checkForSpam('Latest technology news') );         // false
console.log( checkForSpam('JavaScript weekly newsletter') );   // false
console.log( checkForSpam('Get best sale offers now!') );      // true
console.log( checkForSpam('[SPAM] How to earn fast money?') ); // true
```

Что же касается вашего примера кода, то

1. разбиение строки по пробелу на даст вам слова `spam`, вы получите `[spam]`, которое потом не пройдет проверку
2. `arrStr[i].toLowerCase` скобки в функции?
3. `arrStr[i].toLowerCase === 'spam'` вы же только что это вписали в переменную `word` ?
4. `return false` очевидно должен быть вне тела цикла, а то проверяется только первое слово.

```js
'use strict';
const checkForSpam = function (str) {
  let arrStr = str.split(/\b/);

  for (let i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
    let word = arrStr[i].toLowerCase();

    if (word === 'spam' || word === 'sale') {
      return true;
    }

    
  }
   return false;
};

// Вызовы функции для проверки

console.log( checkForSpam('Latest technology news') ); // false
console.log( checkForSpam('JavaScript weekly newsletter') ); // false
console.log( checkForSpam('Get best sale offers now!') ); // true
console.log( checkForSpam('[SPAM] How to earn fast money?') ); // true
```

Comment: Возможен ли более простой (для начинающих учить JS) вариант решения задачи?

Comment: @ViktorHirenko расписал, в чем ошибки в вашем коде.

Comment: @ViktorHirenko в целом, регулярные выражения, которые использованы  в данном решении существуют во всех языках. Тут не важно, начинаете ли вы изучать или нет. Просто это функционал проверки строки на соответствие некоторому шаблону. Правила их синтаксиса одинаковы почти во всех языках. Просто надо знать что они существуют,  и на досуге почитать про основы их применения. К конкретно знаниям js они мало относятся.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
function checkForSpam(message) {
  message = message.toLowerCase(message);
  let result;
    if (message.includes('spam') || message.includes('sale')) {
      return true;
    } else {
    return false;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Можно через тернарный оператор:

```
function checkForSpam(message) {
message = message.toLowerCase(message);

let result = message.includes('spam') || message.includes('sale') ? true : false;

return result;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]